# Have to value else print nothing in php/(postgreSQL/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code. I have to print the whole state name in one column. if any value is there it should print some value in front of that state name otherwise it should print null or zero or empty in front of that state.. state is one table and asset_stage1 is another table. All state name should display on the selection of the date[image]. attaching my current screenshot also. I have to match with state code if state code is there in the state and same state code value is present in asset stage1 it should display value otherwise it should display null

```
       <div class="container">
        <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="date" name="timestamp" class="btn" placeholder="Enter date"/>
        <input type="submit" name="search" class="btn" value="Search by date">
        </form>

<table>
        <tr>                             
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>State Name</th>
        <th>Asset Download Stage1</th>
        <th>Asset Download Stage2</th>
        <br>
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors","Off");
    $pgcon = pg_connect("dbname=nrega host=localhost port=5432 user= postgres");

    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
   //Stage 1               
        $query1 =  " select count(*) as stage1, a.state_code,b.state_name, 
        timestamp::date from asset_stage1 a,states b where timestamp::date >= '$timestamp' and 
a.state_code not in ('06') and a.state_code=b.state_code group by 2,3,4 order by b.state_name
";
//Stage 2  
  $query2 = "select count(*) as stage2, a.state_code,b.state_name, timestamp::date from asset_stage2 a,
  states b where timestamp::date >= '$timestamp' and 
a.state_code not in ('06') and a.state_code=b.state_code group by 2,3,4 order by b.state_name
";
    
// state_code
$query4 = "select distinct state_name, state_code from states order by state_name";
    
     $result4 = pg_query($pgcon,$query4);
    $m=0;
        global $state_code;
    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result4))
    {
        
        $state_name[$m]=$row ['state_name'];
        $state_code[$m]= $row ['state_code'];
           
        $m++;
    }

    
    $result = pg_query($pgcon,$query1);
    $i=0;
        
    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
    {
         if($state_code[$i] == $row['state_code'])
        {
            //echo $row['state_code'];
            $stage1_count[$i]=$row ['stage1'];
        }
        else 
        {
            $stage1_count[$i]=0;
        }
    
        
         $date_store[$i]=$row ['timestamp'];
                        
        $i++;
   }


    $result2 = pg_query($pgcon,$query2);
    $j=0;
    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result2))
    {
             
        if($state_code[$j] == $row['state_code']){
            
        $stage2_count[$j]=$row ['stage2'];  

        }
        else
        {
            $stage2_count[$j]= 0;
        }
        
        //$stage2_count[$j]=$row ['stage2'];
        $j++;
            
    }
     
       
    $len= sizeof($state_name);
    for($i=0;$i<=33;$i++)
    {        
               
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $timestamp;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $state_name[$i];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $stage1_count[$i];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $stage2_count[$i];?></td>
                  
        </tr>
        <?php
    }             
    
    }
    ?>
</table></div>
```

Comment: where is state code? Which is the column of values, Assed Download Stage1 or Assed Download Stage2? What you want to do exactly?

Comment: state code is the column in both the table which have to check and display count of that particular state

Comment: Here are three tables 1st table is "states" 2nd table is "asset_stage1" 3rd is "asset stage2" I have to take the counts of a particular state and have to display in front of that state if it is there otherwise it should display null or 0

Answer (score 0):

For table `asset_stage1`:

```
SELECT state_name, count(*) FROM states, asset_stage1 WHERE states.state_code=asset_stage1.state_code GROUP BY state_name;
```

For table `asset_stage2`:

```
SELECT state_name, count(*) FROM states, asset_stage2 WHERE states.state_code=asset_stage2.state_code GROUP BY state_name;
```